# Getting Error "this app is currently unavailable in your country or region" - Even to my iphone country and app country are same

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I published my ios app on app store. During process i selected `India` in `Pricing and avaibility` section As my app is for Indian audiance and I am from India.

But when i open app link in app store I am getting this error `this app is currently unavailable in your country or region`.

I even checked my app store setting in Iphone there country `India` is selected.

What could be the possible issue.

Comment: Any idea? Im waiting for more than 7 days

Comment: Make a callback request from apple support team. I had a call with them they told to set prices as 0$ in "pricing and avaibility" page. As i my app was free i hadn't added prices. and they told me to wait for 24 hours after 24 hours app was published. But first i suggest you to call them they can tell the exact issue.

Comment: Thanks, the app is now available! You can answer yourself with this response, I will vote it as valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a callback request from apple support team. I had a call with them they told to set prices as 0$ in "pricing and avaibility" page. As i my app was free i hadn't added prices. and they told me to wait for 24 hours after 24 hours app was published. But first i suggest you to call them they can tell the exact issue.